# Google Docs and Ms Word apps not showing in chooser

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, nativescript

In my app I have a link to a docx file located on an server. I want to show this file in another app that can show docx files, like Google Docs or Microsoft Word.
When I display the chooser, neither Google Docs or Microsoft Word are shown (and yes they are installed), it is only the OfficeSuite app that is shown.
Anyone knows why this is?

This is my code:

```
var uri = android.net.Uri.parse(httpUrlString);
var extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());
var mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

var intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

if (extension === "" || mimetype == null) {
    // if there is no extension or there is no definite mimetype, still try to open the file
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/*");
} else {
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimetype);        
}

var packageManager = application.android.context.getPackageManager();
var activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, android.content.pm.PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
var isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

if (isIntentSafe) {
   try {
        application.android.startActivity.startActivity(android.content.Intent.createChooser(intent, "Åben Fil med"));
   } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
   }
}
```

I have tried it on a Sony, LG and a Samsung phone, its the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think I found the reason.
It looks like Google Docs app and Microsoft Word app can't handle http-uri (http://...), but if I download the file to the phone and then parse a file-uri (file:///....) it works well.

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that you have set a default app for files with extension *.docx and this default app is OfficeSuite.

As a potential workaround you can try to change the flag from **MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY** to **MATCH_ALL**

you can also reset your default apps on your device

[how-to-set-and-clear-a-default-app-on-an-android-device](http://www.howtogeek.com/195885/how-to-set-and-clear-a-default-app-on-an-android-device/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortuately this doesn't work. There is no default app for *.docx, and if I change MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY to MATCH_ALL, I still only get to choose OfficeSuite.